# linq cannot see the actual sql query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities

I have a problem with one of my queries using linq 2 entites. I'm trying to view the query before it is generated to the db but without any success. I tried using ToTraceString() but couldn't cause the query could not be cast to ObjectQuery. 
this is my query:

```
  var movies = (from m in watchedRepo.GetAll().Where(c => c.iUserId == userId).ToList()
                           join f in moviePageViewsRepository.GetAll() on m.iMovieId equals f.iMovieId
                            group f by new JoinClass { MovieId = f.iMovieId, Points = m.iPoints }
                           into g
                           orderby g.Key.Points descending , g.Sum(d => d.iScore) descending
                                select new JoinClass { MovieId = g.Key.MovieId, Points = g.Key.Points, PageViews = g.Sum(d => d.iScore) }).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

if I try to execute it from linq I get an out of memory exception.
any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `ToList()` in the first line of your query. This will immediately fetch all rows from `wachtedRepo` with the specified `UserId`.

Because your query will then become a hybrid Linq to Entities / Linq to Objects, you can't cast to an `ObjectQuery`. Is your query still working when you remove `ToList()`?

If you want to see what's really happening in your Sql Server, I would suggest using the Sql Server Profiler tools to view your queries.

Comment: "Is your query still working when you remove ToList()?". I am using Generic Repositories and if I don't use "ToList" then the code shout something about different dbcontext is not allowed in the same query.  can you tell me what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Are you sharing the same DbContext between your two repositories?

Comment: I thought I was, because I am using the Generic Repository Approach:     http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle

Comment: When checking your Generic Repository link, I see the line 'private C _entities = new C();' This means each repository is using it's own context. You should share your Context between all your Repositories to avoid these kind of errors (not sharing the context is a bad idea because if violates the whole idea of repositories).

Comment: I tried doing that before using single ton approach, but the code shouted that the data  context was disposed (null reference exception). How can I execute it so it won't shout?

Comment: @masthagidi Maybe you can start a new question about sharing your context between repositories and show us some code?

Comment: thank you, I started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430880/managing-connections-with-generic-repository-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `watchedRepo` is the Linq to SQL object representing the database connection

```
watchedRepo.Log = Console.Error;
```

All SQL queries will be printed to standard error.

Comment: watchRepo represent my Repository(Generic repositories) which hold inside the dbcontext. So I can't write your code directly.