# Managing connections with Generic Repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I am building a site using entity framework 4.1 and mvc3.  I am using the Generic Repository pattern:
http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle.  I use `ninject` to inject my concretes repositories to the controllers. 
My problem is that each of my dbcontext different and I cannot run complex queries without the code shouting something like "different contexts cannot be used in the same query". I tried using the "singleton" approach but then code shouted something like "tried to enter a disposed object (null reference exception)".
Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Singleton pattern is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. It leads to hard to test code with all kinds of side effects (for example, a disposed DbContext).

The UnitOfWork manages operations on different repositories. It will keep track of all the changes that are made and then it will write those changes in the right order to your database. The DbContext already implements the UnitOfWork pattern (Altough it's nicer to hide the DbContext behind a custom UnitOfWork interface).

If you are already using dependency injection trough NInject you are almost their! You should change the constructors of your Repository to take a DbContext:

```
public class MyRepository
{
   private _unitOfWork;

   public MyRepository(DbContext unitOfWork)
   {
      _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
   }

   ....
}
```

If you then wire the DbContext to NInject with a [InRequestScope mode](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope) everything should work. Your DbContext will then be shared by all Repositories and Ninject will dispose of it at the end of your request.

Comment: Do you mean the constructor of my repository should get a dbContext and ninject will know to automatic inject the dbcontext to the repository class when it being called in the controller?

Comment: plus, I am using Generic Repository as seen in this article: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle     How Can I use the repository constructor there?

Comment: Yes. I mean that the constructor on your Repository should accept a dbContext. If you then use NInject to inject a dbContext with a InRequestScope (meaning that there will be one shared dbContext for each request) then it should work. As far as I can see, the GenericRepository should be modified to take the dbContext in it's constructor instead of creating one for each repository.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm getting your question or not,  but your repositories should be able to work within a "Unit of Work"  which would have a single dbcontext.

I find the best place to start this unit of work is on the begin request, which you  can setup in your global.asax  ( and the end request for tear down )

Comment: "Unit of work" is something I haven't tries yet. Can you tell me why when trying to use "single Ton" pattern I got a null reference (trying to access a disposed object)